# Recommend software for a GCP replacement for a hobby project

Tags: cloud-service, cloud

Please give your recommendation for **the minimum software architecture components** to build my **own Kubernetes cloud** where I will migrate my small internet facing Java hobby project, that I currently host on GCP Kubernetes Engine. I will manage it myself.

GCP is too expensive for my hobby project. If I was to let it run idle 24/7, it would cost over ~$500/mo.

With the cheapest of the big local public cloud providers I found, that I could have the same amount of cpu power and ram at ~10% of the GCP cost, making it feasible for 24/7.

The target needs to have all the basic stuff as GCP currently runs:

- Java workloads on Kubernetes Engine + MySQL + MongoDB.
- Networking configuration for ssl and load balancing.
- Logging, Monitoring and Tracing
- Security and Backups

Cloudflare and Gitlab would be switched to the new server addresses.

Please give your recommendation **what software stack do I need to set up** for it to be an acceptable replacement. I welcome also recommendations what to add to improve security, and any important components I may have missed, which may not be necessary in GCP, but would be valuable in such self-managed cloud (WAF for example?)

I am ok with setting up everything myself from bare Linux.
I want to learn and set it up in the same way as actual "Production environment" would be set up, so no compromises on security.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a second hand Synology NAS with quadcore and SSD:

[image]

- You will need the quadcore because you have to dedicate CPU to Kubernetes
- You will need the SSD because it goes faster
- Ideally find a Synology that can have [RAM boosted](https://nascompares.com/2019/05/09/synology-nas-unofficial-memory-upgrade-guide/).

Now that you have your NAS you can:

- Install [Synology Docker](https://www.synology.com/en-my/dsm/feature/docker) on it (it was lately renamed Container Manager, you can find it in the [Synology packages](https://www.synology.com/en-nz/dsm/packages/Docker?os_ver=6.2&search=docker)).
- Install [MicroK8s](https://flores.eken.nl/migrating-from-synology-docker-to-k8s/) if you want or [Synology CSI Driver for Kubernetes](https://github.com/SynologyOpenSource/synology-csi)

And voilà, bring your images in and you now have your environment at home.

Comment: you are not answering my question about Software. Nowhere in my question I am asking for hardware and that is all you provide. Please share Software recommendations

Comment: Hello @stack3r , I updated my reply